# Custom Silverlight splash screen

Tags: silverlight, splash-screen

Has anyone created a custom Silverlight Splash screen to replace the blue balls circular progress?

Does anyone have a sample or the best way to do this?

Comment: I cudnt help but chuckle at the blue ball reference.. sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this how to:-

[How to: Define a Simple Silverlight Splash Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903962(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903962(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite useful too

[Pro Silverlight 2 in C# 2008 (Google Book preview)](http://books.google.com/books?id=mY2YWBC_M-8C&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=silverlight+splash&source=bl&ots=T1D8WMvi9v&sig=3z93sqcaWG5ltoSA2WXdUdBdtmM&hl=en&ei=QUU2SozLO9OL_Aaps8CBCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=18#PPA172,M1)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project on CodePlex [link text](http://www.codeplex.com/SilverlightLoader)